# How to supply password to runas command when executing it from java

Tags: java, batch-file

I have to run a batch files from a java program which need administrative privilege. I am using the below command

```
runtime.getruntime().exec("runas /user:Admin \"C:\\Program Files\\test.bat\"");
```

but when it get executed its prompt for the password for the Admin account. How can I give the password for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
runtime.getruntime().exec("cmd /C echo YOUR_PASS | runas /user:Admin \"C:\Program Files\test.bat\"");
```

Comment: File exception java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "echo":

Comment: I don't have a windows machine to hand, but can you try "cmd.exe /C echo" instead of "echo"?

Comment: Yep, this helps to call echo cmd. fix this in answer

Comment: @Muzy Keep in mind that when you use `runas`, the initial current folder for the spawned process will change to `%SYSTEM%\system32`

Comment: This works? If I try, it doesn't think my password is correct. If I just run "cmd /C echo|set /p=pwd | runas /user:Admin "cmd"" in a command line, it tells me I have the wrong password, when I don't!

Comment: Does not work for me. Piping the password does not work in Windows 7.

Comment: Can we get an edit on this question?  The accepted answer is clearly wrong and doesn't work.  There is a correct answer below but doesn't give a workaround.

Answer (score 12):

You can't pipe a password into runas, as it requests the password from the terminal, not from stdin. There's no equivalent of "sudo -s".

Comment: Thank you for an insightful answer that makes sense :)

Comment: This is the only correct (and should be accepted) answer.

Answer (score -1):

when i was kid a did this

```
echo Pa$$W0Rd | some_command_expects_it
```

Comment: File exception java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "echo":