# Script cannot read password

Tags: python, elevated-privileges

Python script is designed to run with elevated credentials, unfortunately

1. it still prompts me for password
2. when I enter the correct password it doesn't work

Here is script1, which calls script2 with elevated credentials

```
import os
import sys, subprocess, socket, string
import wmi, win32api, win32con
import win32com.shell.shell as sh   

ASADMIN = '/user:DOMAIN\username'
os.system('"runas /user:DOMAIN\username "D:/Python27/python.exe script2.py sender-ip=10.10.10.10 < password.txt""')
sys.exit(0)

if sys.argv[-1] != ASADMIN:
    script = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
    params = ''.join([ASADMIN] + ['D:\Python27\python.exe',script] + sys.argv[1:])
    sh.ShellExecuteEx(lpVerb='runas',lpFile=sys.executable,lpParameters=params)
    sys.exit(0)
```

Here is script2

import sys, subprocess, socket, string
import wmi, win32api, win32con

for args in [item.strip('sender-ip=') for item in sys.argv[1:]]:

```
userIP = args
userloggedon = ""

# perform system lookup of IP address
userIP = "\\\\" + userIP

pst = subprocess.Popen(
        ["D:\pstools\psloggedon.exe", "-l", "-x",  userIP],
        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr = subprocess.PIPE
    )

out, error = pst.communicate()

userLoggedOn = out.split('\n')[1].strip()
print 'userId={}'.format(userLoggedOn)
f = open('D:\SymantecDLP\Protect\plugins\output.txt', 'w')
f.write('userId={}'.format(userLoggedOn))
```

output.txt is not created

Any ideas?

EDIT

I also read this thread, [How to supply password to runas command when executing it from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811209/how-to-supply-password-to-runas-command-when-executing-it-from-java)

but no matter what I try I keep getting the error

```
Attempting to start c:\test.bat as user "DOMAIN\username" ...
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - c:\test.bat
1326: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

Comment: What do you get if you do `print out`?

Comment: @pss -- where do I keep "print out"

Comment: After the 5th last line that is `out, error = pst.communicate()`

Comment: He publicado una respuesta, pero si usted publica información sobre el error que se obtiene a partir de la ejecución de su código, se podría mejorar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's talk about your problems one at the time.

**1. It still prompts me for password**

In the line

```
os.system('"runas /user:DOMAIN\username "D:/Python27/python.exe script2.py sender-ip=10.10.10.10 < password.txt""')
```

you're providing the password to `script2`. `runas` command still need a password since is trying to run a program as another user.

**2. When I enter the correct password it doesn't work**

Well ...  The code does'n work that's clear. But, you have to be more specific when asking a question. Right now a look to your code and I can see that you're trying to do `ping` on a remote machine.

Might the remote machine has a firewall?
Have you tryed doing `ping` manually?

**Edit:** The output.txt file is not created, and running the script don't tell you nothing about error writting the file, obviously your code is hitting one of the `sys.exit()` lines.

Comment: The output.txt file is not created, and running the script don't tell you nothing about error writting the file, obviously your code is hitting one of the `sys.exit()` lines.

Comment: I am able to ping the remote machine manually. When I manually open the command prompt using elevated credentials and run script2 it works perfectly. To simplify the question I changed script2 ... all machines are pingable

Comment: to address point 1: how do I give the runas command the password. This is my problem.

Comment: OK, thats another question. This question have been answered. I recommend you write a new question let's say `How do I provide the password automatically to the runas command?`

Comment: please answer new question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786511/unable-to-supply-password-to-runas-from-commandline

Answer (score 0):

You can use PsExec
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec

You can supply a username and password and executing does not need to be elevated to admin:

**psexec** [\computer[,computer2[,...] | @file]]\ **[-u user [-p psswd]** [-n s][-r servicename][-h][-l][-s|-e][-x][-i [session]][-c [-f|-v]][-w directory][-d][-][-a n,n,...] cmd [arguments]

Use the -e switch to give the same results as Runas /netonly:

**-e    Does not load the specified account’s profile.**